# How to capture the amount of clicks over a group of loop generated JToggleButtons?

Tags: java, swing, jtogglebutton

I have 20 loop-generated `JToggleButtons` and I need to count how many of them are active.

```
private void generarBotones(){    
    JToggleButton b;
    this.panelCuerpo.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,5));        
    for(int i = 1; i<=20; i++){
        b = new JToggleButton();
        b.setText(String.valueOf(i));
        this.panelCuerpo.add(b);
        b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            int clicks = 0;
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae2){
                clicks = clicks + 1;
                System.out.println(clicks);
            }                
            public void setCantidadBoletas(int clicks){
                cantidadBoletas = clicks;
            }
        });
    }   
}
```

The problem here is that it counts how many times is EACH ONE of them clicked instead of count how many of them are selected.

PS. I tried to use `(b.isSelected())` but `b` needs to be `final` to access it so it wasn't the solution.

Comment: If you declare your JToggleButton inside the loop, then it can be final. But even better, just use an ArrayList of JToggleButtons as a field and iterate through that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you declare the `JToggleButton` inside the loop, you can make it `final`:

```
for (int i = 1; i<=20; i++) {
    JToggleButton b = new JToggleButton();
```

Then you can use `b.isSelected`:

```
    b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            if (b.isSelected())
                clicks++;
            else
                clicks--;
        }
    });
}
```

`clicks` would have to be a class variable.

Comment: The most simple answer.

Answer (score 1):

Create a class attribute that will count the selected toggles:

```
private int selectedCount;
```

Initialize the counter to 0 in your constructor:

```
this.selectedCount = 0;
```

Increment or decrement the counter every time the state of a toggle changes:

```
b.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent ev) {
        if (ev.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED){
             YourClass.this.selectedCount++;
        } else if (ev.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.DESELECTED){
             YourClass.this.selectedCount--;
        }
        System.out.println(YourClass.this.selectedCount);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Suggestions:

- Create a field, `JToggleButton[] toggleButtons = new JToggleButton[20]`
- Or use an ArrayList if you so choose
- In your for loop create your JToggleButton and assign it to the proper array item.
- In the ActionListener simply iterate through the array, counting how many of its JToggleButton items are selected.
- You're done.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to get this done and the best way depends on the rest of your code. I tried to keep it as close to yours.

You can just declare the buttons as `final` inside the loop and keep a global count of the number of buttons selected, which will be modified in the `ActionListener`:

```
public class ButtonsCount extends JFrame {

    int clicks = 0;

    ButtonsCount() {

        JLabel label = new JLabel("0");
        JPanel buttonsPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(4,5));

        for(int i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
            final JToggleButton b = new JToggleButton();
            b.setText(String.valueOf(i));
            buttonsPanel.add(b);
            b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae2){
                    if (b.isSelected())
                        label.setText(String.valueOf(++clicks));
                    else
                        label.setText(String.valueOf(--clicks));
                }
            });
        }

        add(buttonsPanel);
        add(label, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new ButtonsCount();
    }
}
```